# Windows 11, File Explorer, detach tab into a new window?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

Is there a way to detach a tab into a new window?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 11 22H2 and Insider here.

There is a new File Explorer Tab structure and I use it.

(a) The tabs do NOT detach (2 Production 1 Insider machine).

(b) Under Options, Folder Options, General, you can select "Show each folder in its own Window" and have multiple File Explorer windows. The default option is to have all Explorer views in one windows with tabs.

That is the design of the new tabbed Explorer.  It may change in time (but not so far in Insider), so what we have at this point is what we get.

Note: I also have Microsoft Power toys, but no change for tabs in Power Toys.